# asmlibrary with OpenCV and MinGW

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, g++, mingw

I am trying to compile code which uses asmlibrary (by Yao Wei) with MinGW (gcc/g++ 4.7.2), Windows 7, Eclipse CDT (Kepler) , without success. I can compile same library, windows port (asmlibrary.dll) with MVSC, and author also published three files (cygasmlibrary-4.dll, libasmlibrary.a, libasmlibrary.dll.a) which supposedly should work with gcc.
When I try to comppile code which uses asmlibrary, I got this error:

```
13:06:05 **** Rebuild of configuration Release for project AsmLibrarySDK_FIT ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\OpenCV246PC\\build\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o demo_fit.o "..\\demo_fit.cpp" 
g++ "-IC:\\OpenCV246PC\\build\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o video_camera.o "..\\video_camera.cpp" 
g++ "-IC:\\OpenCV246PC\\build\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o vjfacedetect.o "..\\vjfacedetect.cpp" 
..\vjfacedetect.cpp: In function ‘bool detect_all_faces(asm_shape**, int&, const IplImage*)’:
..\vjfacedetect.cpp:85:11: warning: variable ‘pt1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
..\vjfacedetect.cpp:85:16: warning: variable ‘pt2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
g++ "-LC:\\OpenCV246MinGW\\x86\\lib" "-LC:\\asmlibraryFaceXpress" -o AsmLibrarySDK_FIT.exe vjfacedetect.o video_camera.o demo_fit.o -lopencv_calib3d246 -lopencv_contrib246 -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_features2d246 -lopencv_flann246 -lopencv_gpu246 -lopencv_highgui246 -lopencv_imgproc246 -lopencv_legacy246 -lopencv_ml246 -lopencv_nonfree246 -lopencv_objdetect246 -lopencv_photo246 -lopencv_stitching246 -lopencv_video246 -lopencv_videostab246 -lasmlibrary 
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4c9): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10asmfitting12ASMSeqSearchER9asm_shapePK9_IplImageibi'
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x638): undefined reference to `_imp__InitShapeFromDetBox'
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x21c): undefined reference to `_imp__InitShapeFromDetBox'
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x286): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10asmfitting8Fitting2EP9asm_shapeiPK9_IplImagei'
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x442): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10asmfitting12ASMSeqSearchER9asm_shapePK9_IplImageibi'
demo_fit.o:demo_fit.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58c): undefined reference to `_imp__InitShapeFromDetBox'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: demo_fit.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I asked author about this and he replied to me as follows:

> just link like libasmlibrary.a not -lasmlibrary

what I don't understand.
Even if I try from command line, g++ won't accept:

```
C:\Users\Nenad\eclipseCDT\opencv2cookbook\AsmLibrarySDK_FIT\Debug>g++ "-LC:\\OpenCV246MinGW\\x86\\lib" "-LC:\\asmlibraryFaceXpress" -o AsmLibrarySDK_FIT.exe vjfacedetect.o video_camera.o demo_fit.o -l
opencv_calib3d246 -lopencv_contrib246 -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_features2d246 -lopencv_flann246 -lopencv_gpu246 -lopencv_highgui246 -lopencv_imgproc246 -lopencv_legacy246 -lopencv_ml246 -lopencv_nonfr
ee246 -lopencv_objdetect246 -lopencv_photo246 -lopencv_stitching246 -lopencv_video246 -lopencv_videostab246 libasmlibrary.a
```

(error is same as on top of post)
if I try to put -libasmlibrary.a (the of course) I got:

```
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibasmlibrary.a

libasmlibrary gives me g++: error: libasmlibrary: No such file or directory
and so on...
```

As far as I know the only correct way to link this library would be to use -lasmlibrary but then it produces the error mentioned at the top.

BTW, even if I don't include that library at all, I got this error anyway.

Then I asked author again, and he replied to me:

> Code like this g++ a.c -o test libasmlibrary.a -lopencv_library

And even if I do that way (or at least I think I understood him) it yields same result. Of  course I even copied (cygasmlibrary-4.dll, libasmlibrary.a, libasmlibrary.dll.a) into debug directory.

```
g++ "-LC:\\OpenCV246MinGW\\x86\\lib" "-LC:\\asmlibraryFaceXpress" -o AsmLibrarySDK_FIT.exe vjfacedetect.o video_camera.o demo_fit.o libasmlibrary.a -lopencv_calib3d246 -lopencv_contrib246 -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_features2d246 -lopencv_flann246 -lopencv_gpu246 -lopencv_highgui246 -lopencv_imgproc246 -lopencv_legacy246 -lopencv_ml246 -lopencv_nonfree246 -lopencv_objdetect246 -lopencv_photo246 -lopencv_stitching246 -lopencv_video246 -lopencv_videostab246
```

Settings in Eclipse itself are as follows:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Probably this is a newbie question, but I am totally stuck with this.
What should I do to make it compile?

Answer (score 1):

Asmlibrary rather hard to use and not open source as I know. Have you look this project (see chapter 6)  https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code ? I think it will be better for this purpose. Also look at http://www.visionopen.com/downloads/open-source-software/vosm/ . These projects are open source and have much btter description than asm library.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I bought that book just few days ago - I am about to start reading it in few days. I found VOSM on internet last week, but look at who are team members: http://www.visionopen.com/about/team-members/ Wei Yao: Research Engineer - same one who wrote asmlibrary. Do you have any of your experience with VOSM ? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have used vosm, and I have noticed that asm method implemented in vosm works better than one from asmlibrary.

Comment: Thank you - do you have any website or e-mail where I can contact you, if I need some advice?

Comment: My site www.compvision.ru but it's in russian. My e_mail is andreysmorodov(at)list.ru.  PS: (at) = @